# Main menu links not operational on front page when anonymous

Tags: 7, routes

I have two links to 'published content' in main menu. This menu is displayed on all pages, including front page.

When I am logged in as admin, those links work well, but when I am logged out (=anonymous), those links are displayed, but not operational. It is as if they were plain text only.

Yet, when I access content directly with the proper URL as anonymous, those links do work properly in the corresponding page.

So, why don't they work on the front page when using anonymous mode? I have checked page source and the code is the same. I have checked permission and View published content is allowed for anonymous users.

Want could be the cause of this issue?

**Update**

For the records, I have also asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793826/html-links-not-operational-on-front-page). I tried to solve this issue with a Drupal Navigation Menu, but only the Home link works, not the other link.

To solve this issue, I have created my own menu manually. It works, but...

**Update II**

I am using a simple plain vanilla system with panels everywhere. The theme is Versatile. I have header, footer, left, right mini-panels + central content in a default page variant. The right mini-panel just displays an instance of Main Menu. In fact, I have not created users. The site is meant to be used by anonymous people.

**Update III**

The issue only happens when the following CSS is applied:

```
.NCK_Menu {

    font-size: 103%;
    height: 240px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #5E88D0;
    margin: 10px 9px 10px 7px;
    padding: 7px;
    border:none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px;

}
```

It does not make sense !!!

Comment: The clues people gave you on the other thread are sound : z-index issue or Javascript capturing the click event on the link. If the HTML code is the same in the two use cases, it's definitely not a permission issue.

Comment: I'll try to find time to capture the click event and see if it helps solving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The most often reason when you can`t see any kind of links in menu - are permissions for users. So please double check whether all of ones connected to your links (maybe modules/content types or whatever) are enabled for anonymous user.

Comment: That's what I did, but could not find permission issues. I could not find specifics about Main menu. I have enabled all I though might be relevant...

Comment: How do you output your menu? Via page.tpl? Try that snippet. If not try to output it as a simple block

    <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
            'links' => $main_menu,
            'attributes' => array(
              'id' => 'main-menu',
              'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
            ),
            'heading' => array(
              'text' => t('Main menu'),
              'level' => 'h2',
              'class' => array('element-invisible'),
            ),
          )); ?>

Comment: I have updated my question with more info. I don't fiddle with templates -> Pure Drupal configuration.